# Wants to convert a key in a dictionary to clean column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary in a JSON file and I have loaded that JSON file in my Jupyter Notebook. That dictionary has 3 keys

- the first key is the stats key which is the basic stats about the dictionary
- the second key is named questions which is about the questions that were asked in the survey
- the third key is the responses which are the answers to the questions.

My problem is that I have converted the JSON file into DataFrame but the column names which are all the questions asked are not in clean form.[My DataFrame Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeUrF.png)

I want clean questions.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json 

# Load Json File
filepath = "C:/Users/osmi-survey-2016_1479139902.json"
with open(filepath,"r") as openFile:
    my_json_file_health = json.load(openFile)

# Extract questions and responses
questions = my_json_file_health.get("questions", [])
responses = my_json_file_health.get("responses", [])

# Create a list of dictionaries for responses with column names as keys

response_dicts = [{question["question"]: response["answers"].get(question["id"], None) for question in questions}
                  for response in responses]

# Convert the list of response dictionaries to a DataFrame 

responses_df = pd.DataFrame(response_dicts)

responses_df
```

Comment: Tangential to your question, but backticks are not the way to indicate comments in python.  Start comment lines with `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import re, html
tag_re = re.compile(r'(<!--.*?-->|<[^>]*>)')
for col in df.columns:
    df.rename(columns={col: html.escape(tag_re.sub('', col))}, inplace=True)
```